# Can not create sub-interface like `interface gigabitEthernet 2/1.100`

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer, interface

I follow a tutorial, there shows the method of create sub-interface:

[image]

but in my actual situation, I can not do this:

```
Router(config)#interface gigabitEthernet 2/1.100
                                           ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

my router is CGR 1240 in Cisco Packet Tracer.

Comment: You cant expect packet tracer to give all the real world functionalities.

Comment: are all the routers can not create sub interfaces?

Comment: i dont remember, but i dont think they can.

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so you should accept the answer so that it does not keep popping up. Alternatively you can add your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 3):

The GCR routers do not support the sub-interface in Packet tracer, you can change your router to a high-level router, such as `ISR4321`, then you can create easily for experiment:

```
RT1(config)#interface gigabitEthernet 0/0/0.100 
RT1(config-subif)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.100, changed state to up

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.100, changed state to up
```